# Xamarin Android - Will my AlertDialog extension leak memory?

Tags: c#, android, memory-leaks, xamarin.android

I created a simple extension on Activity to show Alert Dialogs. I know from other sources that you need to call the Dispose() method after showing a dialog to prevent memory leaks. Since I don't have a reference to "alert", I cannot call Dispose(). However, I placed my code in a Using statement, but I am not sure if this will work. As a side note, I'm not sure if "EventHandler)null" might cause problems as well.

So, the question is, will this code leak memory? And if so, can you advice me a proper way to write this extension?

```
using DB = System.Diagnostics.Debug;

public static class AndroidExtensions
{
    public static void ShowAlert(this Activity activity, string title, string message, string cancelButtonTitle) {
        if (activity == null) {
            DB.WriteLine("ShowAlert() : Failure showing alert; activity is null");
            return;
        }

        try {
            using (var builder = new AlertDialog.Builder (activity)) {
                if (cancelButtonTitle != "") {
                    builder.SetNegativeButton (cancelButtonTitle, (EventHandler<DialogClickEventArgs>)null);
                }

                using (var alert = builder.Create ()) {
                    if (title != "") {
                        alert.SetTitle (title);
                    }

                    alert.SetMessage (message);
                    activity.RunOnUiThread(()=> {
                        alert.Show ();
                    });
                }
            }
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            DB.WriteLine ("ShowAlert() : Couldn't create alert : " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```